# Which way do props flow with compose()?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

Consider the following:

```
const Foo = defaultProps({
        foo: "foo"
});

compose(
    Foo,
    LoadJson,
    RunParser
)(Bar);
```

In this case, does the prop `foo` flow down through `LoadJson->RunParser->Bar`? Or is it in reverse order, where `foo` flows through `RunParser->LoadJson->Bar` ?

Is there a better way to conceptually envision this rather than a linear flow like that?

Comment: in the docs it says `Composes functions from right to left.` so i'd say it's something like `RunParser(LoadJson(Foo(Bar)));`. See [compose()](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/b4fb08133c95094a4b293a9ab434d1d5dd657527/src/compose.js)

Comment: Thanks! That helps with the order of the function call, though I'm still a bit confused about how props flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/94mjpdso/), the props flow from left to right, meaning props that have been defined on the left are visible to HOCs on the right. So in your case, LoadJson and RunParser should see the prop `foo`

```
const enhance = compose(
    withProps({
    offset: 10,
  }),
  withState('count', 'updateCount', 0),
  withHandlers({
    increment: props => () => props.updateCount(n => n + 1 + props.offset),
    decrement: props => () => props.updateCount(n => n - 1)
  })
)

const Counter = enhance(({ count, increment, decrement }) =>
    <div>
    Count: {count}
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```